# Changing the select tag options using the dom to a default value?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, select, tags

I have the following code where I'm trying to change the defaults for two select inputs and I'm expecting to get *false* for the first dialogue and *hello* for the second dialogue but something is not right.

This is the line in the code that is supposed to make the change

```
var vSelect = document.getElementById('select_1');
    vSelect.options[0].defaultSelected = 1; 

    vSelect = document.getElementById('select_2');
    vSelect.options[1].defaultSelected = 0;
```

Are the `options[index]` used for representing the states within each `select` tag or are they global indices for all the `option` tags within the page?

What I really want to do is to set a specific `select` tag to a default option without knowing the options index in the first place, let me know why that isn't possible if that's the case.

```
<html>
<head>  
</head>
<body onload = "default_settings()">
<style type = "text/css">
body
{
    background-color: white;
}
#select_1, #menu_select_label_id_1, #select_2, #menu_select_label_id_2
{  
    color:#64FFFF; 
    font-size:14px;         
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1.0);    
    text-align: left;
    max-width:90px;
    padding: 4px 4px;
}
</style>
<script language="JavaScript">
function default_settings() 
{           
    var vSelect = document.getElementById('select_1');
    vSelect.options[0].defaultSelected = 1; 

    vSelect = document.getElementById('select_2');
    vSelect.options[1].defaultSelected = 0; 
}
</script>
<select  id = "select_1">
    <option value = "0">true</option>
    <option  value = "1">false</option>
</select>
<label id = "menu_select_label_id_1" for = "select_1">
    boolean 
</label>
<br>
<select  id = "select_2">
    <option value = "0">hello</option>
    <option  value = "1">goodbye</option>
</select>
<label id = "menu_select_label_id_2" for = "select2">
    greeting
</label>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`defaultSelected`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-37770574) is a **boolean** property of the `option` element, indicating whether *that* option is the default option for the select.

So you only set it on the option you want to be the default, and you only set it to a truthy value (which will be coerced to `true`). It's not an index, and it's not a value.

> Are the `options[index]` used for representing the states within each select tag or are they global indices for all the option tags within the page?

They're `option` elements (objects) within a specific `select` element.

> What I really want to do is to set a specific select tag to a default option without knowing the options index in the first place, let me know why that isn't possible if that's the case.

To do that, you have to know *something* about the option (its value, its text) and then search through the options finding the matching one, and set its `defaultSelected` to `true`.

For instance: Here we're finding the option with the value `"foo"` and making it the default:

```
var options = theSelectBox.options;
var n;
for (n = 0; n < options.length; ++n) {
    if (options[n].value === "foo") {
        options[n].defaultSelected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/xabad/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/xabad/1/edit)

Comment: So the index with each select tag for `options` only applies to which value is true or false and each index represents the different `value` and I set those to true or false.

Comment: @user2555139: You're making this way more complicated than it is. Each select has a list of options. Those options are in order. The index of each option is its 0-based position in the list: The first option is index `0`, the second option is index `1`, etc. Each option object has properties, like its `value`, its `text`, its `selected` flag, and its `defaultSelected` flag. That `defaultSelected` flag is a property of the option object, not the select box, and it's not an index. It's a flag. It's `true` on the default option, and `false` on the others (in a single-select box).